# How to use "group" in MongoDB with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using PHP with MongoDB, How can apply below commend inside?

```js
db.event.group({
    keyf: function(doc) {
        return { 
            year: doc.created.getFullYear(),
            month: doc.created.getMonth() + 1,
            day: doc.created.getDate()
        }
    },
    reduce: function(curr, result){
        result.count++;
   },
    initial: {count: 0}
});
```

I have tried below, but NOT working. Looks like not supprt keyf?

```js
$keyf = 'function(doc){return {year: doc.created.getFullYear(), month: doc.created.getMonth()+1, day: doc.created.getDate()}}';
$initial = array('count' => 0);
$reduce = 'function(curr, result){result.count++;}';
$collection->group($keyf, $initial, $reduce);
```

Comment: Group is one of the older implementations in MongoDB. It is actually kind of a wrapper around mapReduce. Generally "grouping" type operations that do not need "mapReduce" complexity have generally been superseded by the aggregation framework. Perhaps with this in mind, and generally speaking, you question would benefit from being reworded to show some of your data, and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are basically counting the amount of documents under a date.

It should be noted that the group command has numerous flaws including:

- Not officially supporting sharding (warning not to use it)
- Is basically JavaScript
- Is Basically a Map Reduce
- Is extremely slow

that means it has since been "deprecated" in favour of the aggregation framework, which in PHP for you would be:

```
$db->collection->aggregate(array(
    array('$group' => array(
        '_id' => array(
             'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$created'),
             'month' => array('$month' => '$created'),
             'year' => array('$year' => '$created')
         ),
         'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
    ))
));
```

To understand what operators I used etc you can look here:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/#exp._S_month
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Answer (score 0):

The PHP driver does have the [`MongoCode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocode.construct.php) class for constructing the JavaScript values that are required.

But you are actually **better off** using the [**`.aggregate()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) command to this as it is "native* code and does not rely on the JavaScript engine. So it is *much* faster at producing results.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "year": { "$year": "$created" },
           "month": { "$month": "$created" },
           "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$created" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

### Data Problem

---

So the aggregate function works are expected, but you seem to have a problem with your test data. Here is cwhat you gave:

```
db.post.insert({'field':'b', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 1')});
db.post.insert({'field':'c', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 1 11:11:11')});
db.post.insert({'field':'d', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 1 12:00:00')});
db.post.insert({'field':'a', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 2')});
db.post.insert({'field':'b', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 2')})
```

And this produces the data:

```
{ "field" : "a", "created" : ISODate("2013-12-31T13:00:00Z") }
{ "field" : "b", "created" : ISODate("2013-12-31T13:00:00Z") }
{ "field" : "c", "created" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:11:11Z") }
{ "field" : "d", "created" : ISODate("2014-01-01T01:00:00Z") }
{ "field" : "a", "created" : ISODate("2014-01-01T13:00:00Z") }
{ "field" : "b", "created" : ISODate("2014-01-01T13:00:00Z") }
```

So it looks like you were trying to add "hours" in the same day to test the grouping. But the arguments to `Date()` are not correct. You wanted this:

```
db.post.insert({'field':'b', 'created':new Date('2014-01-01')});
db.post.insert({'field':'c', 'created':new Date('2014-01-01 11:11:11')});
```

So the whole date as a string and not the "comma" separated values

Comment: Yes, I have tried aggregate before, but result is wrong. Looks like ISO time issue. (I don't sure)

Comment: @YOSTOki Which is why the suggestion to post some data. If that isn't working then the "group" method will likely not work for the same reason. Because it sounds like your dates are actually strings. You can post that content in your question to be sure.

Comment: Yes yes.
Here is my sample data


db.post.insert({'field':'a', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 1')});
db.post.insert({'field':'b', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 1')});
db.post.insert({'field':'c', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 1 11:11:11')});
db.post.insert({'field':'d', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 1 12:00:00')});
db.post.insert({'field':'a', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 2')});
db.post.insert({'field':'b', 'created':new Date('2014, 1, 2')});

use affregate
Date,Count
2014/1/1,4
2013/12/31,2

I prefer
2014/1/1,4
2014/1/2,2

Comment: @YOSTOki Works for me. The way you are creating those dates will not give you the dates you expect though. So that's the problem. Check your data using find and you'll see it clearly

Comment: @YOSTOki So I also just explained the problem with your testing data as well. Change what you are testing on an you will get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for help, finally I realized is mongo problem :(
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6310

Comment: @YOSTOki I would not run to that two year old issue as being a problem, or anything that is likely to change soon. Your "application" **should** be responsible for timezone conversion. Storing dates as UTC is what MongoDB does, and it is considered **best practice**. Think about what happens when you application needs to support another timezone.