# Return the number of documents each month in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a collection in my MongoDB with the following structure:

```
{
        "_id" : "17812",
        "date" : ISODate("2014-03-26T18:48:20Z"),
        "text" : "............."
}
```

I want to use pyMongo and return in a list the number of documents each month from a certain date until now. The way I am doing it now, is to retrieve all the documents without filters and then create the list in Python. I am not sure, but do you know if I can do this one only with pymongo query?

Comment: Basically answered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22709619/2313887) a few questions ago. Just drop the "day" from that and maybe add a "$match" for the date range. Unless you need a further explanation of that.

Comment: I am thinking to change my structure and instead of an ISODate, I will have three different fields for year, month and day. Since I will need many times to group by different ranges each time. But, before that, I will try your post to see if it is easier.

Comment: You really want to keep the ISODate (or actually BSON date that it is) That makes things very flexible and easy to compare. There is no reason why you cannot get the date parts for "hour", "day", "minute" if required. Stick with dates. See the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So getting the counts for a whole month you can use the [date operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) in the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). You can also combine with a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in order to get the range of dates you want.

```js
var start = new Date("2013-06-01");
var today = new Date();

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "date": { "$gte": start, "$lt": today }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "year": { "$year": "$date" },
           "month": { "$month": "$date" },
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Comment: I changed the code a little to fit my interests and now works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris typing mistake from me in the translation which I guess you have already spotted. So please keep your BSON dates. They are both compact and very flexible. As shown.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) in MongoDB which is ideal for this kind of task. It can be used from pyMongo with the [aggregate](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework) method on a collection.